# Missing Method Exception on Groovy Node and Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm not entirely sure if this is a code issue or config issue, but I'm very new to groovy so it could be either. I tried running a more complex script but it didn't work so I tried running a hello world script and it also produced the same issue so that's why I'm not sure if it's code related.

```
node("agentNode") {
    stages {
      stage('Stage 1') {
        steps {
          echo 'Hello world!' 
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

So if I run this script I get the error

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson4198101983862983381.node() is applicable for argument types: (String, hudson4198101983862983381$_run_closure1) values: [agentNode, hudson4198101983862983381$_run_closure1@41005828]
Possible solutions: notify(), wait(), run(), run(), find(), grep()
    at hudson4198101983862983381.run(hudson4198101983862983381.groovy:1)
```

If I try to run it as a pipeline, I get the same error but it says .pipeline() instead of .node().

```
pipeline {
  agent any 
  stages {
    stage('Stage 1') {
      steps {
        echo 'Hello world!' 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My understanding is that Hudson is the build script? I'm utilizing the Jenkins UI to write this script so I think the file may be autogenerated with that name. I'm using groovy 3.0.7. Any help would be immensely appreciated, and any requests for further information can hopefully be fulfilled. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the Jenkins Pipeline plugin installation.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was in the way I was trying to run it. I ended up uploading a Jenkinsfile to my repo and just running it from there without issue